# SSD has primary partition only, no volumes in Windows 10 DISKPART

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, thinkpad, diskpart

After receiving a BSOD, and I try to restart my machine is doesn't work. I get a 0x80070057 error. I can't fix it, it seems. This got me wondering if my SSD had failed.

I am on a Thinkpad T450s running Windows 10.  I was running the OS on a m.2 SSD (256 GB) and had a HDD (500 GB) for files. I originally transferred the OS from the HDD to SSD a while back (Windows 8). The HDD still has partitions for the OS.

When I was trying to get my machine to boot, I ended up using the command prompt and DISKPART, and it looks like the 256 GB SSD is showing up as 115 GB disk with a 32 GB 'primary partition' but has no volumes. What does that mean? Should it have volumes? The HDD have volumes and partitions.

[image: DISKPART disks]

Does this mean it's failed? Disk 3 (if that is the SSD) is online. And I can see it in the boot sequence or bios menus.
[image: bios]

Is the SSD irreparable? Can I reset it? How do I know if it's fixable, that it's useable again even if files are lost. If I try to install Windows again, it doesn't recognize the drive from the recovery Windows installer, for example.

Comment: “Should it have volumes?” - Yes; TestDisk **might** be able to recover the partitions.

Comment: I realize now that the SSD is Disk1 showing up as 20 MB. So this probably means it is done, right? Or do I try TestDisk on this?